# How to convert plain text files into libreoffice cal (Excel sheet) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, file-conversion, plaintext

I have a plain text file containing a huge amount of data. The data's are separated by semicolon and a newline for starting a new line of the following data. Here's a sample:

> "user_id";"device_id";"timestamp";"driving";"id";"onfootoptional";"running";"servertimestamp";"stationary";"tiltingoptional";"unknown";"walking"
>
> 2089;2145;"2016-01-28 14:31:27";28;"b28aa64d-7fe0-49e7-8a1b-b8d37c95a851";1;0;"2016-01-28 15:11:41";18;0;50;1

I have tried to convert using the general method and its not converting. The problem I am finding after converting is the output is somewhat in Chinese letters whereas the text contain only English alphabet and numbers with some special characters. Also the conversion doesn't follow as the text file, like when a newline comes, it supposed to be starting from a new line.

How I really want to convert text files into excel sheet is :

1. Convert each section containing with "**Something or nothing**" followed by a "**;**" into a single cell.
2. Inside the " " field, if it is a string then it needs to be converted as a string and if it contains only Integer numbers then it needs to be converted as an integer number. However if there are a mixture of string and integer then it needs to be converted as a string. Additionally, if an integer number contains any type of special character like " . ", " , ", " - " or " : " then it needs to be converted as an integer plus special characters.
3. When the line of the text is finished with an **newline**, then on the excel sheet the conversion would start from a newline.

Comment: What is the "general method"  -- what specifically did you try?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the built-in function (is this the *general method*?) of Libreoffice should be able to do this?
If not - try [csv2odf](http://csv2odf.sourceforge.net/). This is a very handy tool, especially for many files to convert. It should fit your needs.
I am not sure about the formatting you mentioned. Give csv2odf a try. If it does not what you want it to do, try to specify, what csv2odf does
-you want
-you don't want

Best with proper examples.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your sample into a file called "test.csv" and then double-clicked on it.  Using the default settings, it opened just fine in Calc.

Try trimming down the file to a few hundred rows using a text editor, and then open it.  If that works, then it should give an idea of what is causing the problem.

Maybe the file has newline problems.  Try fixing them like this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32954/use-sed-to-fix-broken-newlines

Also check the encoding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805418/how-to-find-encoding-of-a-file-in-unix-via-scripts

If "huge amount of data" is over 1 million rows, see https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/8631/upper-limit-to-number-of-rows-in-calc/.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. The conversion is not working correctly on my laptop but on someone else's Ubuntu 14.04 it worked. He basically didn't change any setting while converting. He has just followed by clicking next and then Ok finally.

Thanks for your responses.